# dealing with long server side calculations in meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, meteor

I am using jimp (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp) in meteor JS to generate an image server side. In other words I am 'calculating' the pixels of the image using a recursive algorithm. The algorithm takes quite some time to complete.

The issue I am having is that this seems to completely block the meteor server. Users trying to visit the webpage while an image is being generated are forced to wait. The website is therefore not rendered at all.

Is there any (meteor) way to run the heavy recursive algorithm in a thread or something so that it does not block the entire website?

Comment: Not properly speaking an answer, but this is not the way to go imho. Your meteor server is not supposed to encode images. The good practice would be, as far as I can tell, to handle the encoding on a dedicated server. You can choose whatever architecture will suit you. In an AWS context, I would get an additional EC2 instance optimized to handle the job and I would use slingshot to upload from client to S3. The additional server would handle the new files either from API calls from your main, either by watching the S3 files. If it is a small app, use Meteor.defer(), as @StephenWoods answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node (and consequently meteor) runs in a single process which blocks on CPU activity. In short, node works really well when you are IO-bound, but as soon as you do anything that's compute-bound you need another approach.

As was suggested in the comments above, you'll need to offload this CPU-intensive activity to another process which could live on the same server (if you have multiple cores) or a different server.

We have a similar problem at Edthena were we need to transcode a subset of our video files. For now I decided to use a meteor-based solution, because it was easy to set up. Here's what we did:

1. When new transcode jobs need to happen, we insert a "video job" document in to the database.
2. On a separate server (we max out the full CPU when transcoding), we have an app which calls [observe](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe) like this:

```js
Meteor.startup(function () {
  // Listen for non-failed transcode jobs in creation order. Use a limit of 1 to
  // prevent multiple jobs of this type from running concurrently.
  var selector = {
    type: 'transcode',
    state: { $ne: 'failed' },
  };
  var options = {
    sort: { createdAt: 1 }, limit: 1,
  };
  VideoJobs.find(selector, options).observe({
    added: function (videoJob) {
      transcode(videoJob);
    }, });
});
```

As the comments indicate this allows only one job to be called at a time, which may or may not be what you want. This has the further limitation that you can only run it on one app instance (multiple instances calling `observe` would simultaneously complete the job). So it's a pretty simplistic job queue, but it may work for your purposes for a while.

As you scale, you could use a more robust mechanism for dequeuing and processing the tasks like Amazon's [sqs](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) service. You can also explore other meteor-based solutions like [job-collection](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for `Meteor.defer(yourFunction)`.

Relevant Kadira article: https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-performance-101/content/make-your-app-faster

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response! I wrapped my function inside Meteor.defer(). However, it still seems to delay everything. Is it plausible that the function is so 'intensive' that it sucks all the processing power? Not leaving anything for the server to send the webpage to the client?

Comment: Hm I guess that's plausible.  I haven't done image processing so I'm not really sure.

Comment: Yeah this won't work. Node runs in a single process, so this just allows the method to complete but then eats all of the CPU afterwards.

Comment: Meteor doesn't take advantage of clustering automatically though?

Comment: Wow, I guess I didn't realize that.

Comment: FYI, `Meteor.defer()` is a per-client call.  So it would simply not block the current client's queue of calls. It doesn't affect the overall server or event-loop (as I understand it).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments and answers! It seems to be working now. What I did is what David suggested. I am running a meteor app on the same server. This app deals with the generating of the images. However, this resulted in the app still eating away all the processing power.

As a result of this I set a slightly lower priority on the generating algorithm with the renice command on the PID. (https://www.nixtutor.com/linux/changing-priority-on-linux-processes/) This works! Any time a user logs into the website the other (client) meteor application gains priority over the generating algorithm. Absolutely no delay at all anymore now.

The only issue I am having now is that whenever the server restarts I somehow have to rerun or run the (re)nice command.

Since I am using meteor up for deployment both apps run the same user and the same 'command': node main.js. I am currently trying to figure out how to run the nice command within the startup script of meteor up. (located at /etc/init/.conf)

Comment: I'm glad you got something working. It seems like running the process on a separate server would be an easier solution than modifying its scheduling priority. Side note, if my advice worked it would be nice (pun intended) to throw an accept and/or upvote my way. :)