# Updating large object makes Meteor server unresponsive

Tags: mongodb, meteor

My meteor application has to update documents with large and deep nested fields (~250 KB) and the operation takes a long time, the order of a few minutes. I tried the update operation with `Meteor.setTimeout` but the server does not accept any more requests from the client till the update completes. Is there a way to perform long running db operations without blocking clients?

Alternatively, is there a way to make the update operation faster in mongodb?

Thanks

Comment: There are two possible things going on here. If it's slow for all users, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35706776/dealing-with-long-server-side-calculations-in-meteor). If it's slow only for the caller because he/she can't initiate another method call, you may just need a [this.unblock()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/method_unblock).

Comment: It was blocked for all users, so I'll give meteor-job-collection a shot. Thanks! Also, is there any way to make the update operation itself run faster?

Comment: I can't really say without knowing more detail. The job collection idea will work if the app is CPU-bound. If it's also locking the database, then offloading the task to another server may not necessarily help. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: meteor-job-collection did it, thanks. I think the update operation in this case was CPU bound because of the documents' structure. The update operation still takes its sweet time, but the rest of the application doesn't get blocked.

Comment: Excellent. I'll mark this as a duplicate for completeness.